# Bootstrap modal popover with varying context dependent locations

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, popover

Bootstrap modal popover looked like a good fit for my needs (modal functionality with a popover look): 
https://scruffles.github.io/BootstrapModalPopover/

I need to display the popover in different locations depending on where the user clicked, which I think is a common scenario (if you have 20 x 6 elements on a page, where the content is dynamic, you cannot even define 20 x 6 popover divs separately, it's not even possible).

The problem is that once the popover is displayed the first time, it sticks to that initial location. How can I overcome this? Here's a very simplified Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/csabatoth/NJZLh/5/

```
<div class="page">
    <div data-bind="foreach: items">
        <button class="btn" data-bind="text: txt, attr: { id: refid }, click: function(data,event) { $root.displayPopover(data) }" ></button>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="dialog" class="popover">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <h3 class="popover-title" id="popoverTitle"></h3>
    <div class="popover-content" id="popoverContent">
    </div>
    <div style="float: right; padding: 0px 15px 15px 15px">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-bind="click: function(data, event) { return $root.hidePopover(); }"><i class="icon icon-remove"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    function ItemObj(id, txt, msg) {
        var self2 = this;
        self2.id= id;
        self2.txt = txt;
        self2.msg = msg;
        self2.refid = "ref" + id;
    }

    self.items = ko.observableArray([
        new ItemObj(1, "First", "blabla1"),
        new ItemObj(2, "Second", "blabla2"),
        new ItemObj(3, "Third", "blabla3"),
        new ItemObj(4, "Fourth", "blabla4")
    ]);

    self.displayPopover = function(data) {
        $('#dialog').modalPopover({
            target: '#' + data.refid,
            placement: 'bottom'
        });
        $('#popoverTitle').html("Sample " + data.txt);
        $('#popoverContent').html("Sample editable content " + data.msg);
        $('#dialog').modalPopover('show');
    }

    self.hidePopover = function() {
        $('#dialog').modalPopover('hide');
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

You can see how I dynamically generate the ids (refid) for the elements where I can tie the popover to. The ids are generated well, and work for the first show. The problem maybe is in the modal popover plugin, in the `$.fn.modalPopover`? Once it's created the data, it never overrides it, so the second call won't modify anything:

https://github.com/scruffles/BootstrapModalPopover/blob/master/src/bootstrap-modal-popover.js#L118

`if (!data) $this.data('modal-popover', (data = new ModalPopover(this, options)))`

If the problem is in modal popover itself, I'm all right to modify that too.

Comment: I'll try a push request, it says it's for repositioning: https://github.com/scruffles/BootstrapModalPopover/pull/7

Comment: Also note that my JSFiddles reference the RAW js custom binding file on GitHub. If you use Chrome, JSFiddle won't load that (because of mismatching MIME type). I primarily develop with FF + FireBug, I don't have such problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kyle Lee's fork solves the problem!
http://jsfiddle.net/csabatoth/NJZLh/8/

`The fiddle's source is the same as before, the only difference that this time I include the fork's js instead of the original branch's js`

https://github.com/liyuankui/BootstrapModalPopover

I discovered a cosmetic bug (if you'd have multiple direction popovers), see in my comments below.

Comment: +1. You should accept your own answer, perhaps helping other people in the future, also marking the question answered...And, eventually, you will get a shiny self-learner badge :)

Comment: I'll, but it's not allowed. I also have to note, that I've found a bug with the above fork: if the repositioned popovers would have different orientation, then the arrow part of the popover cloud gets messed up. I fixed that by aligning all popovers to the same direction (I had right and top popovers, now I only have right, so the bug is not visible). I'll create a fiddle for the bug and report it on GitHub.

Comment: Demonstration of the bug: http://jsfiddle.net/csabatoth/NJZLh/9/ but once again, if someone doesn't need multiple directions, it's fine.

Comment: Does this work anymore?  It does not seem to load for me

Comment: It definitely worked back in 2014. The PR I referenced did not get merged though. I'd try again with the main scruffles repo (https://scruffles.github.io/BootstrapModalPopover/) and use Bootstrap 3.x instead of the ancient 2.x.